# Is there a way to bind any command to any key/mouse button I want?

Tags: pc, dark-souls-2

It seems that I am not able to bind movements to my mouse keys.  It seems as though you're restricted to what you can bind period.  Some command subsections only allow keyboard commands while only others allow mouse commands.

Comment: Are you using a Razer mouse by any chance?

Comment: No, just a standard Logitech mouse.  That you have to resort to a programmable mouse, though, is pretty lousy.  From really needs to get their game together if they're going to port to the PC.  /rant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While From software did a great job with the new keyboard/mouse control system for Dark Souls 2 (DS1 was absolutely atrocious) they are still not quite there in the pc community. Don't get me wrong, the game works brilliantly but thats beside the point. As far as I know, there is no way to bind keyboard to mouse controls in game. There is a menu that allows some controls for the mouse to be used on the keyboard but I doubt thats what you're looking for. If you happen to have a Steelseries mouse you can actually bind keyboard keys to mouse buttons using the Steelseries Engine. I don't know if other companies have this, but this is the only way I can think of to be able to do what you're looking to do. 
 PS: I forgot to mention that a wired ps3/xbox controller can be your best friend when playing any of the souls games. I bought one from a friends recommendation when I had just got DS1 on steam and that was a LOT easier than trying to figure out the damn keyboard and mouse controls!

Comment: They need to start hiring PC gamers to test their betas.  The entire game is essentially unplayable for me.  Controls for PC games should be fully customizable.  Also, they still haven't replaced the controller button icons with keyboard keys.  Sloppy, and they promised they were going to do better.  Well, I guess they technically did, but it's not good enough.  Anyway, I am ranting (as I well should).

Comment: They did have a PC beta, as you may be aware of, BUT it was mainly focused on testing their servers, connectivity, and other bugs. From Software should get a little leeway since the souls series (with exception to Demon's souls) is their FIRST foray into the PC world. Judging by the progress they made from DS1 to DS2, they could have a nearly perfect product if they choose to continue developing games for the PC. DS2 was one of the absolute best games I have ever played on launch. I experienced few bugs and nothing that made the game unplayable *cough* THIEF *cough*.